# WP8 In-App list in the Developer Dashboard

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-phone-8

Where do I add "In-App" purchases in the developer dashboard when submitting an app for WP8?
Every other platform iv'e ever used has this simple list(Win8/Metro, iOS and Android)... where is it for WP8 submission??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your application profile on the Dashboard, select "Products", then click the "Add in-app product" link:

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you very much, don't know how I could not find it, I will have to try that when I get to work and give you your credits ;)